# White background during fadeOut() and fadeIn()

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently I'm using this code to create a slideshow in my homepage:

```
var images = [
    "/d/assets/images/IT/homepage/slider-1.jpg",
    "/d/assets/images/IT/homepage/slider-2.jpg",
    "/d/assets/images/IT/homepage/slider-3.jpg",
    "/d/assets/images/IT/homepage/slider-4.jpg",
    "/d/assets/images/IT/homepage/slider-5.jpg",
];

var imageHead = document.getElementById( "slider-home" );
var i = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  $('#slider-home').fadeOut(200,
    function() {
      imageHead.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[i] + ")";
      i = i + 1;
      if (i == images.length) {
        i = 0;
      }
      $('#slider-home').fadeIn(200)
     }
    );

  }, 5000);
```

The code works perfectly and change the background-image every 5 seconds. Unfortunately between every change there is a small white background and the transition not appear to be "clean" and "fluid" like the Ryanair slideshow in homepage: https://www.ryanair.com/it/it/

Where is the problem that generate this and how I can solve it?

Comment: The background appears when two pictures have an alpha lower than 1. You should have two images on top of each other and should not hide the first image before the second one fully appears.

Comment: You are fading out an element, switching the background, then fading it back in. The flash occurs at that moment when it is faded out and before it is faded in. To get the fade effect on the Ryanair site where you get some fade overlap you need to have 2 elements, one with the current background and one with the next background, and fade one out while you fade the other in. You can use the `queue: false` option to the jquery animate to enable having two animations running at once.

Answer (score 1):

You're fading one image out, waiting for that transition to complete, then fading the next one in. That's effectively transitioning to the page background in between the images.

Making those transitions simultaneous by stacking two elements and transitioning between them would help, but it still wouldn't be perfect: you still wind up with the background peeking through during the transition while both images are partially transparent.

Instead, to get a smooth transition, just fade out the "top" image in the stack, revealing the one behind it:

```js
yourswap = function() {
  if ($('#div1').is(':visible')) {
    fadeout = "#div1";
    fadein = "#div2";
  } else {
    fadeout = "#div2";
    fadein = "#div1";
  }
  // fade one out, then fade the other in
  $(fadeout).fadeOut(function() {
    $(fadein).fadeIn()
  });
}

badswap = function() {
  $('#div1, #div2').fadeToggle(); // transitions both elements in and out
}

goodswap = function() {
  $('#div1').fadeIn(0); // make sure the background element is visible
  $('#div2').fadeToggle(); // transitions the top element in and out
}
```

```css
.block-div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  position: relative
}

#div1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: brown;
  display: none;
}

#div3 {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="yourswap()">Your transition</button>
<button onclick="badswap()">Simultaneous transition</button>
<button onclick="goodswap()">Single transition</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="block-div" id="div3">(This is the page background)</div>
  <div class="block-div" id="div1">1</div>
  <div class="block-div" id="div2">2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example
https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/ehKpi

No need to write JS for that.
But through CSS it's possible.

CSS :

```
animation: 30s slidy infinite;
```

set property "animation:30s slidy infinite;" (number of seconds to change the Image in slider.)